# Как отсортиваровать простой список?

Tags: python, сортировка

Работаю с БД. При запросе выводит список, назовём к примеру - игроков:

```
i = ''

for num, (nick, counts) in enumerate(cursor.fetchall(), 1):
    i += f"{num}.\t{nick}\t{counts}\n"
    
print(i)
```

---

```
1.      emarfi  2
2.      emarfi  77
3.      iframe  1
4.      emarfi  15
5.      iframe  23
6.      emarfi  42
7.      iframe  3
```

Как отсортировать по убыванию значения после имени?

Пробовал `sorted`, `rstrip`, но это только что-то не то. Может есть какие модули?

Comment: По убыванию чего? Если вам не помог sorted, значит, вы просто "не умеете его готовить".

Comment: @EzikBro, по убыванию значения после имени. Простите, забыл дописать, изменил вопрос.

Comment: правильнее всего отсортировать данные на стороне БД: `select ... from ... where ... ORDER BY column_name DESC` ;)

Comment: @MaxU, напишите ответ. Я галочку поставлю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется если данные и так уже вычитываются из БД, то и сортировать их лучше непосредственно в БД. Например для таблицы `user` со столбцами (`name`, `user_rank`) запрос мог бы выглядеть так:

```
SELECT name, user_rank FROM user ORDER BY user_rank DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Если на стороне питона, а не БД, то `sorted` всё же должен сработать, только нужно добавить правильный параметр `key`, скорее всего вам нужен `key=lambda x: -int(x[1])`.

Но возможно ещё, если `fetchall` возвращает генератор, а не готовый список, то нужно будет сначала от него взять `list`, чтобы нормально потом отсортировать. Насчёт сортировки прямо генератора я не уверен.

Comment: а почему не воспользоваться параметром `reverse=True` ?

Comment: @MaxU Я интуитивист, на мелочи внимание не обращаю ))  Спасибо )

Comment: "я - интуитивист"... универсальный ответ :) возьму на вооружение

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Но удобнее будет оказалось со стороны БД.

Comment: @hoojpop Со стороны БД это в общем и правильно. БД для этого лучше предназначена, чем Python )

Comment: @MaxU Да ну если всё-равно выражение писать, то можно и без `reverse` ))